Making 3d object fade in/out in Unity
Well, there is a lot of questions related to the topic but nothing has helped me so far.
I'm trying to make an object appear/disappear smoothly by changing it's transparency, however transparent shaders make object always a bit transparent.
I tried setting up my own shader, but considering it was my first try it didn't end up quite well. I got an not transparent object that disappears, but it looked like shit (no shades etc).
My question is - how do you do it? Or rather, what would I have to change in my code to make it work or in a shader to make it not look bad?
FadeIn
    private IEnumerator FadeIn(Renderer renderer)
    {
        Color color = renderer.material.color;
        color.a = 0;
        renderer.material.color = color;

        float duration = 1.0f;
        float elapsedTime = 0;

        while (elapsedTime < duration)
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            color.a = Mathf.Clamp01(elapsedTime / duration);
            renderer.material.color = color;
            yield return null;
        }

        color.a = 1;
        renderer.material.color = color;
    }

My custom shader (
Shader "Custom/TransparentDefault"
{
    Properties
    {
        _Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
        _MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        LOD 200

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _Color;

            v2f vert(appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _Color;
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}



if you want shadow in vert frag shader,you should set lightMode and use Legacy SHADOWCASTER pass , like
Tags
{
"RenderType" = "Opaque"
"LightMode" = "ForwardBase"
}
UsePass "Legacy Shaders/VertexLit/SHADOWCASTER"

Make sure to use correct formatting for your answer and correct grammar
